# ¿Cómo mejorar el resultado de esta consulta?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT m.Codigo + '-' + CAST(rb.Orden AS VARCHAR(30)) AS Matriz 
   FROM   RequerimientoDetalle rd 
      INNER JOIN RequerimientoBase rb ON rd.ReqBaseId = rb.Id 
      INNER JOIN Seccion s ON rb.SeccionId = s.Id 
      INNER JOIN Matriz m ON s.MatrizId = m.Id 
      INNER JOIN Periodo p ON rd.PeriodoId = p.Id 
      INNER JOIN vInstitucion v ON rd.InstitucionId = v.Id 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN EvaluacionCGR ECGR ON ECGR.ReqDetalleId = rd.Id 
         WHERE (rd.InstitucionId = 233) AND (ECGR.Evaluacion = 0)
```

Que genera el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podria cambiar el query que de el siguiente resultado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que cada Matriz se posicione de manera horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta query:

```
                SELECT m.Codigo + '-' + CAST(rb.Orden AS VARCHAR(30)) AS AMC ,
                  (SELECT m.Codigo + '-' + CAST(rb.Orden AS VARCHAR(30)) AS ADC 
                FROM RequerimientoDetalle rd 
                INNER JOIN RequerimientoBase rb ON rd.ReqBaseId = rb.Id 
                INNER JOIN Seccion s ON rb.SeccionId = s.Id 
                INNER JOIN Matriz m ON s.MatrizId = m.Id 
                INNER JOIN Periodo p ON rd.PeriodoId = p.Id 
                INNER JOIN vInstitucion v ON rd.InstitucionId = v.Id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN EvaluacionCGR ECGR ON ECGR.ReqDetalleId = rd.Id 
                WHERE (rd.InstitucionId = 233) AND (ECGR.Evaluacion = 0) and m.Codigo like '%ADC%'

                  ) AS ADC,
                  (SELECT m.Codigo + '-' + CAST(rb.Orden AS VARCHAR(30)) AS LyC 
                FROM RequerimientoDetalle rd 
                INNER JOIN RequerimientoBase rb ON rd.ReqBaseId = rb.Id 
                INNER JOIN Seccion s ON rb.SeccionId = s.Id 
                INNER JOIN Matriz m ON s.MatrizId = m.Id 
                INNER JOIN Periodo p ON rd.PeriodoId = p.Id 
                INNER JOIN vInstitucion v ON rd.InstitucionId = v.Id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN EvaluacionCGR ECGR ON ECGR.ReqDetalleId = rd.Id 
                WHERE (rd.InstitucionId = 233) AND (ECGR.Evaluacion = 0) and m.Codigo like '%lyc%'

                  ) AS LyC,
                  (SELECT m.Codigo + '-' + CAST(rb.Orden AS VARCHAR(30)) AS MyE 
                FROM RequerimientoDetalle rd 
                INNER JOIN RequerimientoBase rb ON rd.ReqBaseId = rb.Id 
                INNER JOIN Seccion s ON rb.SeccionId = s.Id 
                INNER JOIN Matriz m ON s.MatrizId = m.Id 
                INNER JOIN Periodo p ON rd.PeriodoId = p.Id 
                INNER JOIN vInstitucion v ON rd.InstitucionId = v.Id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN EvaluacionCGR ECGR ON ECGR.ReqDetalleId = rd.Id 
                WHERE (rd.InstitucionId = 233) AND (ECGR.Evaluacion = 0) and m.Codigo like '%mye%'

                  ) AS MyE
                FROM RequerimientoDetalle rd 
                INNER JOIN RequerimientoBase rb ON rd.ReqBaseId = rb.Id 
                INNER JOIN Seccion s ON rb.SeccionId = s.Id 
                INNER JOIN Matriz m ON s.MatrizId = m.Id 
                INNER JOIN Periodo p ON rd.PeriodoId = p.Id 
                INNER JOIN vInstitucion v ON rd.InstitucionId = v.Id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN EvaluacionCGR ECGR ON ECGR.ReqDetalleId = rd.Id 
                WHERE (rd.InstitucionId = 233) AND (ECGR.Evaluacion = 0) and m.Codigo like '%AMC%'
```

Comment: Francisco Acevedo dice que ha devuelto mas de un valor.

Comment: entonces lo realizaría en un procedimiento almacenado, el cual se encargue de llenar una nueva tabla con los datos como los solicitas "clasificadamente"